# React native custom map marker issue in iOS release config

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to get a react native app that's already working nicely on android to run on iOS. It uses `react-native-maps` to display a map view, and custom markers on it. When running the app in debug config, the markers look the way should, like below.

[image]

But when I run it in release config or send it to testflight, marker icons go haywire, and looks like this.

[image]

The implementation is as follows (trimmed the code down to essential parts so it may have missing variables etc...)

```
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
 
const marker = require('../assets/marker.png');
const markerDark = require('../assets/marker-dark.png');
const customMapStyle = require('../assets/customMapStyle.json');

export default function DisplayMapView () => {
  return (
    <MapView {...mapProperties} ref={mapRef} style={mapStyle} onPress={onMapPress}>
      <For each="markerData" of={markerDatas || []}>
        <Marker
          showsTraffic={false}
          showsCompass={false}
          mapType={'terrain'}
          {...markerData}
        >
          <Text>
            {markerData.label}
          </Text>
          <Image
            resizeMethod="resize"
            resizeMode="center"
            style={styles.marker}
            source={shouldDarkMarker(markerData) ? markerDark : marker}
          />
        </Marker>
      </For>
    </MapView>
  );
}
```

How can I get the custom markers working in release config?